# How to reset a loop that iterates over a set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, loops, set

How can I reset a loop that iterates over a set? A common answer for iterating over a list is to reset the index you are using to access the list, however sets do not support indices.

The point is to be able to iterate over a large set of objects, perform some action against each element until a result matches the result I require. The functionality I am searching for is the ability to *reset* a loop. Meaning restart the iteration from the beginning to ensure I visit every element again for whatever reason.

How can I reset the following loop?

```
for element in some_set:
   print element
   if element + offset == needed_result:
      # reset
```

I'm using python 2.7 for this specific problem, but I'd also welcome python 3 solutions.

Comment: *"reset the index you are using"* - that doesn't work in a `for` loop either. What's the broader context, the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: what do you mean by *reset*? You make `break` from the loop and start iterating again, but why? Sets are unordered you know i hope

Comment: What do you mean by ``reset``? It's not as if the set is "exhausted", it will always contain the same elements, it's immutable - and unlike lists, it's also unordered.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the broader context is exactly this. I am iterating over an unordered large list, where for each element I must hash the value and compare it to some value until I find a certain value matching the hash, however this is irrelevant. I would like to be able to reset this iteration to begin again at a given condition.

Comment: @Chris_Rands if I am iterating over a set (meaning incrementing the element I am accessing by one), I'd like to reset the iteration and begin the exact same loop at the first element ensuring I can visit every value once.

Comment: @Mike sets immutable? you mean frozensets - right?sets are very mutable

Comment: Why do you want to reset? do you want to match multiple conditions? Sets are unordered : "the first" is misleading - if you do not change your codition you create a complicated endless loop with that - you are not very clear what you wat to acomplish by that.

Comment: @PatrickArtner incorrect, while sets are unordered - they do not change their order arbitrarily. I require specific functions to be run over a large set of values and I need to check the results of these calculations against some known solutions for which I do not have a known input for. There are multiple conditions that could be met against the same set, same calculations, but I cannot tell which ones will be met first.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Could you add the details of the problem you're trying to solve to your question?  A good solution to your problem is not going to be resetting the iterator inside the for loop, but running  a new for loop. You may even need something as simple as `all(any(map(check, my_set)) for check in checks)`

Comment: @PatrickArtner right, sets are mutable. I must have mixed up something in my mind about sets and tuples. So while tuples are immutable they are ordered, with sets it's the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do so would be by using [iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html). You could define an iterator by simply calling `iter()` on your set, and call its `next` method on each iteration. When the condition is met, you can simply create again the iterator object from the set and repeat the process:

```
s = {1,2,3,4,5}
s_ = iter(s)
# Just a counter to avoid endless loop
cont = 0
while cont < 10:
    try:
        i = next(s_)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    # Some condition
    if flag == True: 
        # Reset the iterator when the condition is met
        s_ = iter(s) 
        continue
    cont += 1
```

Comment: Upvoted endless loop - cool .... you are aware that `cont` is a `NameError` to be happening and even if not - it will never rise above 1 (if 2 is the 2nd value iterated) .. and still be an endless loop ;)

Comment: Well there is no info on what condition would end the loop. Added a counter so it is more clear that it should break under some condition... but with no further info I'm only guessing here @PatrickArtner

Comment: Might want to wrap that `next` in a `except StopIteration: break`.

Comment: An iterator is exactly what would solve my issue. This question does not care for _what_ the reset condition is - only that there will be one. The question is for _how_ to perform the reset on loop of a specific data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a neat trick that takes **any kind of iterable** (including sets), and returns an instance of a `ReIterable` class (our short name for "resettable iterable").

We can then use the re-iterable in a `for` loop as `for r in my_reiterable`, just as we would use the original iterable in `for i in my_iterable`.

Inside the `for` loop, whenever the conditions are right for re-setting the loop, **we only have to call the `reset()` method on the re-iterable**.

Here's an example usage with a set `s` (but it could just as well have been a list or any other iterable):

```
s = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}
r = ReIterable(s)
for i in r:
    print ('In for loop,', i)
    if (i == 'c'):
        resp = str(input('Found "c". Do you want to reset?(y/n):'))
        if (resp == 'y'):
            r.reset()
```

Here's the output (Note that the first time the user was prompted to reset, the user responded with a `y`, causing the set to be iterated all over again. The second time the user was prompted to reset, the user responded with a `n`, and the loop proceeded without getting reset):

```
In for loop, e
In for loop, c
Found "c". Do you want to reset?(y/n):y
In for loop, e
In for loop, c
Found "c". Do you want to reset?(y/n):n
In for loop, a
In for loop, d
In for loop, b
In for loop, f
```

How does this work? The wrapper class ReIterable makes use of the protocol between a `for` loop and an iterable.

Here's what the `ReIterable` class looks like (but you only need to know how to **use** the class, though, as shown above):

```
class ReIterable:
    def __init__(self,original):
        self.original = original
        self.iterator = iter(original)
        self.reset_flag = False

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if (self.reset_flag):
            print ('In __next__(), reset_flag True')
            self.iterator = iter(self.original)
            self.reset_flag = False
        return next(self.iterator)

    def reset(self):
        self.reset_flag = True
```

**Note:**

Besides the fact that it supports the reset operation, the `ReIterable` class essentially delegates all the iteration work to the original iterable or its iterator. The actual "resetting" involves junking the old iterator and getting a new one (as also in @yatu's answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would just convert the set to a list and use a while loop:

```
sett = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'}
lisst = list(set)

position = 0
while (position <= 8):
   element = lisst[position]
   print element
   if element + offset == needed_result:
        position = 0
   else:
        position += 1
```

Comment: sets do not support indices

Comment: I realized that after you made your comment, you need to convert it to a list, see edit